# ngx-translate JSON not found

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular5, ngx-translate

I realize this is a common issue and have been scouring this repo's support tickets and Stack Overflow looking for why I can't get this working. None of the many suggestions I've tried have worked. I'm confused because my setup is simple and in no way (that I can see) different from the example code setup shared in the ngx-translate repo.

I'm using Angular 5.1.0 along with Angular CLI 1.7. Webpack and ngx-translate versions are as follows:

```
   "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "~3.8.1"
```

http://localhost:4200/src/assets/i18n/en.json resolves to the file correctly in the browser, so the file is in the correct location for the default configuration outlined in the ngx-translate README.

Here are the relevant files:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

/*
 * Main app component that houses all views.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

  store: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private translate: TranslateService) {
    // translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { RootComponent } from './root.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from '../db/in-memory-data.service';

import { AppInterceptor } from './_core/app.interceptor';
import { FooterComponent } from './_core/footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './_core/header/header.component';
import { DataService } from './_core/data.service';
import { DataResolver } from './_core/data.resolver';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppGuard } from './app.guard';

import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { GatewayService } from './shared/gateway.service';
import { WindowRefService } from './window-ref.service';

/*
* Main module for the app that boostraps everything.
*/
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }) // Remove to use real HTTP calls
    ],
    declarations: [
        RootComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        AppComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AppGuard,
        DataService,
        DataResolver,
        MessageService,
        GatewayService,

        WindowRefService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AppInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }

// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

I've tried all the common solutions, including using the CopyWebpackPlugin to try to resolve the webpack bundling, adding the i18n directory to the assets list in angular-cli.json, and explicitly passing my path to TranslateHttpLoader like so:

```
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
```

None of these approaches have worked.

Is there something very basic I'm missing in my setup? I feel like I've just been looking at it too long at this point. :/

Comment: can you check whether your file is available at  `http://localhost:4200/i18n/en.json` or not?

Comment: I think the problem is `Interceptor`, your `AppInterceptor` prevent http call for `assets/i18n/` json file. you should bypass that `http` call.

Comment: I removed all reference to AppInterceptor and got the same error.

Comment: I tried making the file available at http://localhost:4200/i18n/en.json and even when it was available I got the 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue, the fix was removing AppInterceptor, as @hrdkisback suggested in a comment above. I thought I had removed all instances of it, but I hadn't. Once that was done, I was able to access the translation file.

Comment: There is a way to bypass Interceptors for the ngx-translate HttpLoader. Please see this github issue: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/921

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename you resource files en.json to en.txt and change the app.module.ts:

`export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/resources/', '.txt');
}`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me after looking it  into 1.5 hours...

Answer (score 1):

Change your JSON path as follows :

```
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", ".json");
```

As `./` chooses current directory.